# Problems using EXPECT is a BASH shell script

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, expect

This is the code (bash script):

```
echo "Pass for router:"
read -s pass


/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
spawn ssh 192.168.10.1 -l root 'opkg list-installed' > list-installed.txt
#echo @pass
expect "*password:*"
send "$pass\r"
interact
EOD
```

Problem is that it's returning nothing. It doesn't create the local file "list-installed.txt"

What could be wrong with this?

Answer (score 5):

Single quotes have no special meaning in expect. Use double quotes.

Additionally, use `expect eof` instead of `interact`, since there's nothing to actually interact with once you enter the password -- you're just waiting for the command to complete.

Comment: +1 `expect eof` was the key for my situation.